# BitBucket trigger jenkins build via post not working when windows auth enabled

Tags: asp.net-mvc, continuous-integration, jenkins, bitbucket

In BitBucket, I have a POST service setup with hopes to remotely trigger a build on my jenkins CI server but when I push to my BitBucket account, it appears to not work.

I have windows auth enabled on the server that hosts jenkins.

I tried supplying the POST service with this url:

```
http://username:password@CiBuilderServer.com/job/MyProject/build
```

This url works in my browser. I tried curl and received this error:

```
curl: (47) Maximum (50) redirects followed
```

I'm guessing however BitBucket makes the request, the credentials are not sent correctly.

IIS Log:

```
x.x.x.x POST /job/MyProj/build - 80 - x.x.x.x Bitbucket.org 401 2 5 62
```

Any ideas or workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling both basic auth and windows auth did the trick. I know bitbucket is written in Python. Maybe Python and Windows Auth don't play well together?